# SceneKit – access destination color in shader modifier for blending

Tags: scenekit, metal

Is there a way to access last fragment color (destination color) in Metal shader modifier similar to `gl_LastFragData` in `GLES`?

My goal is to perform custom blending using shader modifiers (SceneKit's `SCNBlendMode`s do not suffice in my situation). Currently I'm using `SCNTechnique` with 3 passes (render the destination, render the source, combine) to achieve this and that seems like a major overkill to me + it is really hard to have several blending groups without introducing new passes.

`SCNProgram` does not seem like an option for several reasons (I'm using [PBR](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlightingmodelphysicallybased), tessellation/subdivision; I'd rather stick with using techniques for now I guess).

I've tried using `#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480635/6192057), but it doesn't work even for GLSL shader modifiers (I'm using `Xcode 9.0` and `iOS 11`).

I've also stumbled upon [this wonderful gist](https://gist.github.com/j-j-m/4ebd20e1fdabdfb0f2c2ce86cbeaba45) that has SceneKit's default metal shader implementation, but it seems that blending is not performed there. Which makes me wonder if that is the reason why I can't find any destination color reference: blending happens somewhere else.

Is `SCNProgram` is the only way besides the `SCNTechnique` atrocity?

**P.S:**
The only mention of `gl_LastFragData` in the context of `Metal` that I've found is in chapter `4.8 Programmable Blending` of [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) which would be helpful if I could somehow access the `[[color(0)]]` or something similar in shader modifier (if that's even possible).

Comment: I'm wondering this as well. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Same here. Any news about this one?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to check that that you hadn't overlooked the fragment entry point?

In the documentation it says: "Use this entry point to change the color of a fragment after all other shading has been performed."

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean by accessing the "last fragment color" but thought it might be worth mentioning.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypoint/1523342-fragment